# I am doing a React project and I have this error in my project which relates to Google Maps

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

This is the error I get:

> google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated, use the standard addEventListener() method instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
>
> The feature will continue to work and there is no plan to decommission it.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by using `useEffect(() => {})`

```
const [handleScroll, setHandleScroll] = useState(); 
const heightChange = () => {
let scrollTop = window.scrollY,
    minHeight = 10,
    logoHeight = Math.max(minHeight, 71 - scrollTop/10);
setHandleScroll(logoHeight);}
useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener('scroll', heightChange);

return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', heightChange);
};


}, []);
```

Comment: ok , but can you share your code to  solve this error...?